# Inconsistent system of linear inequalities.

Tags: inequality, linear-programming

I have to prove the following system is inconsistent:

$\{x+y-t\geq1, -x+2y+z\geq1,-3y-z+t\geq0 \}$

By Fourier's method, I have eliminated the variables $x$ and $z$ and I have arrived to the following inequality: $y-t\leq-1$. I do not see why this inequality should imply that the system is inconsistent. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Any tips?

Comment: Just summing up gives $0 \geq 2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally missed that.